# mod_rewrite on Statusbar

Tags: php, html

file.php

```
include('site.html');
```

site.html

```
<a href='folder/hello.html'>Link</a>
```

When you hover over Link, it says folder/hello.html in the statusbar. How can I make it show hello.html instead? I cannot modify site.html.

Comment: _"I cannot modify site.html."_ - neither can `mod_rewrite`; it rewrites HTTP requests reaching the server, it has _nothing whatsoever_ to do with manipulating HTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about replacing `include('site.html');` in *file.php* with `<a href='hello.html'>Link</a>`?

Answer (score -1):

You can use mod_rewrite for this

RewriteRule ^.*hello.html /folder/hello.html

And change the link to hello.html